# How to put Silverlight application inside Flash file(swf - browser independet which run with flash player)

Tags: javascript, silverlight, actionscript, flash

i have created a silverlight application , but i need to embed it to a Flash file(swf) which it runs with Flash Player ( whithout using browser), I had found a [solutions](http://sorokoletov.com/2010/01/hosting-silverlight-in-flash/) to call it using javascript, but it still needs my flash file run inside the browser, dose any one can help me, Either to run js inside swf (without need of browser) or any other way that i can embed my Silverlight application inside Flash.

Thanks

Comment: Why not do it all in Flash or all in Silverlight, mixing the two is very strange scenario.

Comment: You simply can't do that (embed a silverlight application inside a swf file).

Comment: that's right, this case also was quite strange , as i found out atleast need a browser to use js to able to do some about it :) thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you are going to need to host this in a browser to have any hope of getting this to work.